# Error when downloading Window support software under Boot Camp

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp

Currently, I have already upgraded to Mac OS X Lion.

But an error occurred(Progress to the last 99%) that when I trying to downloading Windows support software via Boot Camp 4.0.

It says "Can't install Windows Support Software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server".

How can I do ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had that exact same problem. I don't have an easy fix for it but what I did was just keep retrying and it eventually made it to 100% and worked fine.